# Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file - Import by BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to import data from Excel into SQL.

I try to use the BCP command, this the code:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp DB.dbo.Table IN "C:\\File.csv" -c -T -S ServerName\instancename'
```

but I get this error:

```
output
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is config
ured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
NULL
```

Also if I remove the `serer` property' it not sucsess' this the code:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp DB.dbo.Table IN "C:\\File.csv" -c -T'
```

the error:

```
output
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL
```

I can't know what to do...
I'm look for many solutions but - NOTHING

Comment: Error is quite clear on what is wrong. It couldn't find specified server/instance name. You specified your server and instance name as "ServerName\instancename". Are you sure that is correct? seems to me like you copied placeholder from command definition..

Comment: @Aarlaneth - also if I remove it, it not sucsess: `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp Diyur.dbo.ShiluvimFileTable IN "C:\\ShiluvimFile.csv" -c -T'` the error: `Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file`
Look at the question, I edit it

Comment: Did you try googling second error to find solution to it? First thing that pops for me is [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221578/error-microsoftodbc-driver-13-for-sql-serverunable-to-open-bcp-host-data-f) which lets me believe this is issue with filesystem permissions.

Comment: @Aarlaneth - I saw this solution but I don't know how to do this. And also - I need to run this command on many server...

Comment: Is the `C:\File.csv` file resident on the SQL Server's C: drive, or on your own? Also note that I used a single backslash character.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Ths C drive is on my computer, but also if I put a shard dirve I get the same error ,Also if  I use only single backslash character - Iget the same error

Comment: The file has to be resident somewhere that the SQL Server can access it. Specifically, the domain/Windows account under which the SQL Server service executes requires file system and/or share permissions that will allow it to read the file.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - SQL have permissions to access to it, What can I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many google searches and my many attempts
I found the problem:

1. I write the code by `Bulk insert` and not with `BCP command`,
   this is the full Code:

---

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
( [Field1] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Field2] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Field3] nvarchar(max) NULL ); 


BULK INSERT #TempTable  FROM ''<FullPath>\FileName.csv'' WITH --if the path is in the network - need to write the Full-path of the drive
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
MAXERRORS = 10000,
KEEPNULLS, 
ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',
FIRSTROW = 2,
CODEPAGE = ''1255''
);

select * from #TempTable
Insert into TableNameInDB(Field1,Field2,Field3)
select * from #TempTable
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

1. The path of the file was with the full path of the drive (if the drive map in the network)
2. I save the file by `csv` file